# Downcast object to unknown class

Tags: java, oop, casting, javafx

I would like to cut down in code by using the same variable name for two possible objects (JavaFX `Chart` objects in this case). The reason for this is because after this `for loop` some processing to the chart happens that is identically.

I tried downcasting the chart but it gives me an "unknown class" error.

```
Chart chart;

if (chartClass.equals(LineChart.class))
    chart = new LineChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);
else
    chart = new AreaChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);

for (int i = 0; i < variablesToPlot.length; i++) {
    series[i] = new LineChart.Series<Number, Number>();

     // this chart must be LineChart or AreaChart (but not general chart) for getData() to work
    ((chartClass) chart).getData().add(series[i]);  
}

// here some chart processing that is equal for both charts
```

What I am looking for kind of sounds like dynamic typing (which Java is not capable of as far as I know), but is there a way to solve this problem other than writing the code twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the declaration of `Chart chart` to `XYChart chart`.

The common superclass of [LineChart](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/chart/LineChart.html) and [AreaChart](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/chart/AreaChart.html) is [XYChart](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.html).
You will then be able to cast it to `XYChart` and use the `getData` method on it.

It will result in:

```
XYChart chart;

if (chartClass.equals(LineChart.class))
    chart = new LineChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);
else
    chart = new AreaChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);

for (int i = 0; i < variablesToPlot.length; i++) {
    series[i] = new LineChart.Series<Number, Number>();

     // this chart must be LineChart or AreaChart (but not general chart) for getData() to work
    chart.getData().add(series[i]);  
}
```

Comment: The cast in the for loop is not necessary. XYChart in the top is enough. Thanks! :)